# Energy estimate for a friedrich system with relaxation and periodic boundary conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, transport-equation

I'm considering the following system of pdes
$$ \partial_t u +  \sum\limits_{i=1}^3 \mathcal{A}_i\partial_{i} u = -\mathcal{R} u. $$
Where the matrices $\mathcal{A}_i$ are symmetrics, $u$ is valued in $\mathbb{R}^p$, on $\Omega = \left[0,1\right]^3$ with periodic boundary conditions. The matrix $\mathcal{R}$ is diagonal with positive coefficient.
And i would like to show that the energy norm of $u$ is decreasing
$$\partial_t \| u \| _{L^2(\Omega)^p} \leq 0.$$
Here is what i've done so far :
I took the scalar product with $u$ in $\mathbb{R}^p$ and i integrated over $\Omega$,
$$ \frac{d}{dt} \frac{1}{2} \int_{\Omega} \vert u(t,x) \vert ^2  dx +\sum\limits_{i=1}^3\int_{\Omega} \left(\mathcal{A}_i \partial_i u(t,x),u(t,x) \right) dx = - \int_{\Omega} \left(\mathcal{R}u(t,x),u(t,x) \right) dx  
$$
And i know that i have to use the periodic boundary condition to show that $\int_{\Omega} \left(\mathcal{A}_i \partial_i u(t,x),u(t,x) \right) dx = 0$ but i'm stucked, i only managed to show that $$
\int_{\Omega} \left(\mathcal{A}_i \partial_i u(t,x),u(t,x) \right) dx = - \int_{\Omega} \left(\mathcal{A}_iu(t,x),\partial_i u(t,x) \right) dx $$ which isn't that helpful.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What you've derived **is** helpful.  Since $\mathcal{A}_i$ is symmetric you have that
$$
\int_\Omega (\mathcal{A}_i u, \partial_i u) = \int_\Omega ( u, \mathcal{A}_i\partial_i u) = \int_\Omega (  \mathcal{A}_i\partial_i u, u) 
$$
and so you've derived an equality of the form $X = -X$, which implies that $X=0$.  Now you can conclude.

Comment: Thank you, this is what i was missing.